# Duplicate entry save - grails

Tags: hibernate, grails

I know the error is causing in the following snippet of my code, when I comment to only save the separation, it does not convert it. And when I put to save the conference first and then the separation of the duplicate enty error.

```
def separation = null
  separation = new Separation(
  expedicao: expedition,
  dateInit: new Date(),
  user: springSecurityService.currentUser,
  typePackage:dist.box,
  package:package
)    
try {
  Separation.withTransaction {
    separation.conference = new ConferenceQuantity()
    separation.conference.getList (listProducts.id)
    separation.conference.typeConference = true
    //separation.conference.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    separation.save (flush: true, failOnError: true)
  }
} catch (RuntimeException ex) {
  log.error "** Saving error: $ {separation} $ {separation.conference}"
  launch new RuntimeException ('Error creating partition')
}
```

Someone knows how to stop giving this error:

> ERROR 27-08-2018 00:11:54 [JDBCExceptionReporter]: Duplicate entry
>   '1-416834-1' for key 'tenant_id'

Comment: Add right after Separation.withTransaction{ next line of code:
separation = Separation.get(separation.id)
It should help because your current separation is in another session and it may produce issues

Comment: So I can not get the id of my separation, because I just created it and have not persisted it in mysql

Comment: Why are you creating `separation` instance outside of the new transaction scope? imho rethink what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: the truth is that already tried in many ways, this is the one that is more certain, but still presents error for a case, where this snippet of code is often called by a loop